# Offline Downloading Windows Tools / SDK

Tags: windows, download

Our strict proxy rules are not allowing downloads from microsoft, where a download Manager is provided. As an example i wanted to download the Windows SDK, it will download a 1MB File which then starts downloading the packages (eg. cab files) Is it possible to do an offline download? There aren't any option on microsofts page.

thanks

Comment: Why are there not other options because Microsoft doesn't want to offer other options.  If there is an offline download then it would be on the same download page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a link on the download page that took me to [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442) which has the ISO's for download?

Answer (score 1):

Which SDK version do you want to download? For Windows 7 there is an ISO (see the answer of cjb110). For Windows 8.x there is only this installer. You can run this installer on a second PC (whih has a good internet connection) and select to download all files. Take the complete downloaded folder to the PCs where you want to install the SDK, now you no longer need an active internet connection.

Comment: Hi thanks magicandre1981 for the additional Information,  i will download now the iso for 7, but good to know, that i could download it onto another pc and copy the folder without any problem